# How to configure Meteor build and run for a Cordova build through NGINX + SSL?

Tags: cordova, ssl, meteor, nginx

i have a web application that is used to build Cordova android app.
The application is built for an ubuntu server where is running a Nginx with SSL (Mongo is hosted on mongolab). On production i use a NodeJS 0.12.X, but in dev i still use meteor shell.

When i build the application i run this command :

```
meteor build  ../../build/mercanet/ --mobile-settings settings.json --server=https://myIP
```

When i run the application on server here is the command (on prod server i use node :

```
meteor --settings settings.json --mobile-server https://myIP --port 3000
```

If i open a browser to https://myIp i can check that websocket works well so my nginx is well configured. But if i open the application in my android emulator, it fails to connect : https://myIP/sockjs/info?cb=x3i8q_or0y (cancelled)

I tried without SSL and i replace HTTPS by HTTP in meteor shell and it worked, so i'm wondering what i should do to use HTTPS with MeteorJS and Cordova.

For information here is the content of **meteor_runtime_config** on Cordova :

```
{"meteorRelease":"METEOR@1.2.1", "ROOT_URL":"https://myIP/", "ROOT_URL_PATH_PREFIX":"", "DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL":"https://myIP", "autoupdateVersionCordova":"ee806cb3e614acbfaad7031f7964c254c9fc7e39", "appId":"1rm26uv1lh7ui31i489b2"}"
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Did you get this resolved ?

Comment: In fact it was an error on Nginx configuration : we had the feeling that it worked in the browser but in fact the websocket failed and it was the polling fallback tha run.
I will push the nginx config i finally use in the response of the post.

Answer (score 2):

It was an nGinx config error. Here is the config that works well and tha use nodeJs only for websocket, and Nginx for all assets :

```
upstream my_nodejs_upstream {
  server 127.0.0.1:YourNodePort;
  keepalive 64;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name my_nodejs_server;

    root /home/www/project_root;

    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://YOUR_HOSTNAME$1 permanent;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl spdy;
  listen [::]:443 ssl spdy;
  server_name my_nodejs_server;

  root /home/www/project_root;
  more_clear_headers 'X-Powered-By';

  ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/privkey.pem;

  # serve images
  location ~* "^/(favicon\.ico|img\/.*\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png))$" {
    root /home/YOUR_DEPLOYED_METEOR_APP/bundle/programs/web.browser/app;
    access_log off;
    expires 1w;
  }

  # serve css and js
  location ~* "^/[a-z0-9]{40}\.(css|js)$" {
    root /home/YOUR_DEPLOYED_METEOR_APP/bundle/programs/web.browser;
    access_log off;
    expires max;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_pass http://my_nodejs_upstream/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_read_timeout 240s;
  }
}
```